# Is there a way to add a phone authentication to the default laravel auth scaffolding

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Please is there a way to add phone number authentication to the default laravel auth scaffolding?

Comment: what do you mean by phone number authentication?

Answer (score 0):

In LoginController add this method

```
// for laravel v5.4+
public function username()
{
    return 'phone_number'; // HERE WRITE YOUR FIELD NAME
}

// for older laravel versions
protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only('field_email', 'field_passwd');
}
```

This will override your default trait's (AuthenticatesUsers) method for getting the custom username for Authentication.

Also don't forget to make that field in migration as "unique" like this:

```
$table->string('phone_number')->unique(); // HERE WRITE YOUR FIELD NAME
```

This will optimize your DB structure and speed up your auth system.